# Uncaught TypeError: video.removeAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, object, video

I am using this function for a HTML5 video player project. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-html5-video-player--pre-8905) is the place I got the code from. I am comparatively new to the Javascript so having some problem understanding the code fully.
Whenever the function is executed, it simply logs :

```
Uncaught TypeError: video.removeAttribute is not a function

   videoPlayer.init @   vp.js:8
   (anonymous function) @   vp.js:13
   (anonymous function) @   vp.js:15
```

Same happens to `video.addEventListener` if Line 8 is commented out.

Console logging video on 7th line outputs `[]` and clicking on it, it expands to :

```
   0: video#video
   length: 1
   video: video#video
   __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

So, how the variable video can be accessed inside init(). What are the ways to implement it? Any guidelines or answers would be so helpful. Please direct me on my mistakes.
By the way, this is my first question on stackoverflow network.

Here's the Javascript Code :

```
(function( window, document) {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
        var videoPlayer = { 
            init : function() { 
                var that = this; 
                document.documentElement.className = 'js';  
                console.log(video);
                video.removeAttribute('controls'); 
                video.addEventListener('loadeddata', this.initializeControls, false); 
           }
        }; 

        videoPlayer.init(); 

}( this, document ));
```

Here's the HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Custom HTML5 Video Player</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="margin: auto; width: 1000px;">
    <h1> HTML5 Video </h1>
    <div id="video_container">
        <video id="video" controls width="1000px" preload>
            <source src="vdo/Mauka.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using one `s` too many in `getElementsByTagName`: it returns a DOMNodeList, not an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `getElementsByTagName()` function returns a list of elements, not a single one. You seem to have only one, so you can access the first element in the list like this `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];`. Try this:

```js
(function( window, document) {
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        var videoPlayer = { 
            init : function() { 
                var that = this; 
                document.documentElement.className = 'js';  
                console.log(video);
                video.removeAttribute('controls'); 
                video.addEventListener('loadeddata', this.initializeControls, false); 
           }
        }; 

        videoPlayer.init(); 

}( this, document ));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Custom HTML5 Video Player</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="margin: auto; width: 1000px;">
    <h1> HTML5 Video </h1>
    <div id="video_container">
        <video id="video" controls width="1000px" preload>
            <source src="vdo/Mauka.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if all you want is hide the video controls and play automatically once loaded, you don't need any JavaScript. Try this:

```html
<video id="video" width="300px" autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Brother, I already did it. It returns me : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined   videoPlayer.init @ vp.js:8(anonymous function) @ vp.js:13(anonymous function) @ vp.js:15. Now the Console logging returnes " undefined ".

Comment: That's because your object `videoPlayer` does not have a function called `initializeControls`. What are you trying to achieve? If you want the video to start automatically, simply add the `autoplay` attribute and you don't need the whole JavaScript.

Comment: I tried your last edit and removed controls attribute from video tag, also commented out `video.removeAttribute('controls');` and I also have created `initializeControls()` beneath `init : function() {},` but now it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: video.addEventListener is not a function` . How can this error be eradicated to attach `addeventListener `to `video` variable or to `getAttributes` of it or do similar stuff with it..??

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to implement a custom HTML5 Video Player. I got the code from [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-html5-video-player--pre-8905) page. Wrote down whole code according to the authors instructions but getting above stated error. If possible please take a short look at the link and reply. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you read the full article? You copied some code from there without reading the article and you expect it to work. You're missing 90% of the code. Anyway, the article offered the [entire code sample](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-html5-video-player--pre-8905/attachment), so download it, unzip it, and run the **video.html** file in the **source** folder.